# PostGIS transforms st_dwithin to && on geography column without preserving the custom spatial reference system

Tags: postgresql, postgis

When I use st_dwithin on a geography column with a GIST index, the explain plan shows that the narrowing condition on the index scan is changed into a && condition. With this different condition, the result set is missing rows that are included if a st_dwithin is performed using a full table scan when there is no index.

The condition in the explain plan without an index is

```
st_dwithin(
  geog,
  '010100002010A4000000000000006066400000000000000000'::geography,
  '3'::double precision,
  false
)
```

but the explain plan indicates that it is changed into the following when the column has a GIST index

```
geog && _st_expand(
  '010100002010A4000000000000006066400000000000000000'::geography,
  '3'::double precision
)
```

The geography column has a custom spatial reference system that is not being preserved in the transformation into a && condition. The custom spatial reference system is a sphere where the radius is such that one degree is equal to one meter of great-circle distance. So that a point of (0 0) is one distance away from (0 1).

The setup code is below

```
-- Insert the custom spatial reference system into the db.
insert into spatial_ref_sys values (42000, 'customsrs', 1,
     'GEOGCS[
       "Normal Sphere (r=57.2957795)",
       DATUM["unknown",
         SPHEROID["Sphere",57.29577951308232087679,0]
       ],
       PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
       CS[ellipsoidal,2],
       AXIS["latitude",north],
       AXIS["longitude",east],
       UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]
     ]', '+proj=longlat +ellps=sphere +R=57.29577951308232087679 +no_defs');

-- Create a new table with a geography column in the new spatial reference system.
CREATE TABLE geographytest(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, geog geography(POINT, 42000));

-- Insert some data around the dateline
insert into geographytest (gid, geog) values
(1, 'srid=42000;POINT(179 0)'),
(2, 'srid=42000;POINT(178 0)'),
(3, 'srid=42000;POINT(-179 0)'),
(4, 'srid=42000;POINT(-179 90)'),
(5, 'srid=42000;POINT(0 0)');


-- Select all points within a distance of 3 from POINT(179 0).
--   The expected 3 points are returned, with st_distances of 0, 1 and 2.
select
 gid,
 st_distance(
   geog,
   'srid=42000;POINT(179 0)',
   false
 ),
 st_dwithin(
   geog,
   'srid=42000;POINT(179 0)',
   3,
   false
 )
from
 geographytest
where
 st_dwithin(
   geog,
   st_geogfromtext('srid=42000;POINT(179 0)'),
   3,
   false
 );

-- Create a GIST index on our geography column
CREATE INDEX geographytestindex ON geographytest USING gist (geog);
VACUUM analyze geographytest (geog);

-- Now select again using the same query.
--   Now only one result is returned, the row that has POINT(179 0).
--   The explain plan indicates that the index scan is using 
--   Index Cond: (geog && _st_expand('010100002010A4000000000000006066400000000000000000'::geography, '3'::double precision))
--   when performing the select.
select
 gid,
 st_distance(
   geog,
   'srid=42000;POINT(179 0)',
   false
 ),
 st_dwithin(
   geog,
   'srid=42000;POINT(179 0)',
   3,
   false
 )
from
 geographytest
where
 st_dwithin(
   geog,
   st_geogfromtext('srid=42000;POINT(179 0)'),
   3,
   false
 );
```

Increasing the st_dwithin distance to 230000 instead of 3 returns all three of the expected rows, since that is their distance in srid 4326.

How can I get PostGIS to use my custom spatial reference system in the query when an index is present on the column?

Comment: Quick question: why are you using `geography` if you're relying on a custom SRS? Have you tried with `geometry`?

Comment: @JimJones I need to be able to find points crossing the dateline and around the poles.

Comment: Are you getting false results? The `&&` condition should only be an indexable pre-filter, and `_st_dwithin` should still be called to eliminate false positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `_st_expand`. This function expands the bounding box of the given geography. Looking at the [code](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/933e23cd13891ff2bfe72b9bad9633a812333ae4/postgis/geography_measurement.c#L454), we can see that the desired distance is modified using WGS84 radius, so the custom CRS is indeed ignored. You can [report](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/report) the bug if you wish.

```c
/* Read our distance value and normalize to unit-sphere. */
distance = PG_GETARG_FLOAT8(1);
/* Magic 1% expansion is to bridge difference between potential */
/* spheroidal input distance and fact that expanded box filter is */
/* calculated on sphere */
unit_distance = 1.01 * distance / WGS84_RADIUS;
```

Comment: @loveridge you won't get a better answer than this one. Either you report a bug (which imho would be appropriate) or change your data type to `geometry` - of course, if it is applicable. cheers